# Get a Position from Gyroscope and Accelerometer

Tags: position, accelerometer, gyroscope

I implemented a mathematical method to calculate the position using an IMU that gave me accelerometer, gyroscope and pitch yaw and roll data. The problem was that the IMU was not robust enough to my project so I bought a more precise IMU.

The problem is that it does not give me pitch yaw and roll data, it only gives acceleration and gyroscope data. I know that it easy to calculate pitch and roll, but I guess that I need a magnetometer to calculate yaws value.

I need to calculate the position using this IMU so I do not know what it would be the best method.

1) Get yaw data using mathematical method (I do not know if it is possible).
2) Integrate magnetometer to get yaw data, so I will have enough information to get the position.
3) Use other mathematical method to calculate the position that only needs accelerations and gyros.

Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you get acceleration, you could integrate it to get velocity and integrate the velocity to get position. but you need both acceleration and time.